# Symfony2 Doctrine Unrecognized field:

Tags: symfony, doctrine, field

I've created an Entity to store some data i'm pulling via an api

When i try to findByOne to see if the entry already exists, i get an error saying the field is not recognised.

I've done a php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
I can see the table in my mySQL manager with the right fieldname 'StadiumID'
So why cant doctrine find it when i do `findByOne();`
My Entity Class:

```
<?php

namespace FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Stadium
 *
 * @ORM\Table("fp_stadium")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\StadiumRepository")
 */
class Stadium
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="StadiumID", type="integer", length=2, nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $stadiumID;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Name", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="City", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="State", type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
     */
    private $state;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Country", type="string", length=2, nullable=false)
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Capacity", type="integer", length=32, nullable=true)
     */
    private $capacity;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="PlayingSurface", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $playingSurface;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set stadiumID
     *
     * @param integer $stadiumID
     * @return Stadium
     */
    public function setStadiumID($stadiumID)
    {
        $this->stadiumID = $stadiumID;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get stadiumID
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getStadiumID()
    {
        return $this->stadiumID;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Stadium
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set city
     *
     * @param string $city
     * @return Stadium
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get city
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * Set state
     *
     * @param string $state
     * @return Stadium
     */
    public function setState($state)
    {
        $this->state = $state;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get state
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getState()
    {
        return $this->state;
    }

    /**
     * Set country
     *
     * @param string $country
     * @return Stadium
     */
    public function setCountry($country)
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get country
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    /**
     * Set capacity
     *
     * @param integer $capacity
     * @return Stadium
     */
    public function setCapacity($capacity)
    {
        $this->capacity = $capacity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get capacity
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getCapacity()
    {
        return $this->capacity;
    }

    /**
     * Set playingSurface
     *
     * @param string $playingSurface
     * @return Stadium
     */
    public function setPlayingSurface($playingSurface)
    {
        $this->playingSurface = $playingSurface;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get playingSurface
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPlayingSurface()
    {
        return $this->playingSurface;
    }
}
```

The code i'm using to add the data if it does not exist and to update it if it does exist:

```
<?php

namespace FantasyPro\DataBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\Stadium;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return $this->render('DataBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
    }

    public function updateStadiumAction(){
        //get list of stadiums
        $client = $this->container->get('fantasyapi');
        $stadiumData = $client->Stadiums();
        //var_dump($stadiumData);
        //get the entity manager
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repo = $em->getRepository('DataBundle:Stadium');
        $log = $stadiumData;

        foreach($stadiumData as $stadium){
            // Get the current stadium in the list
            $criteria = array("StadiumID" =>$stadium['StadiumID']);
           var_dump($criteria);
            $storedStadium = $repo->FindOneBy($criteria);

            if (!$storedStadium) {
               /* throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                    'No product found for id '.$stadium['StadiumID']
                );*/
                //no stadium exists with the StadiumID passed
                //create a new entry
                $entry = new Stadium();
                $entry->setStadiumID($stadium['StadiumID']);
                $entry->setName($stadium['Name']);
                $entry->setCity($stadium['City']);
                $entry->setState($stadium['State']);
                $entry->setCountry($stadium['Country']);
                $entry->setCapacity($stadium['Capacity']);
                $entry->setPlayingSurface($stadium['PlayingSurface']);
                $em->persist($entry);
                $log .= 'Added New Stadium: '.$stadium['StadiumID'].' : '.$stadium['Name'].'<br>';
            }else{
                $storedStadium->setStadiumID($stadium['StadiumID']);
                $storedStadium->setName($stadium['Name']);
                $storedStadium->setCity($stadium['City']);
                $storedStadium->setState($stadium['State']);
                $storedStadium->setCountry($stadium['Country']);
                $storedStadium->setCapacity($stadium['Capacity']);
                $storedStadium->setPlayingSurface($stadium['PlayingSurface']);
                $em->persist($storedStadium);
                $log .= 'Updated Stadium: '.$stadium['StadiumID'].' : '.$stadium['Name'].'<br>';
            }
        }
        //$em->flush();
        return $this->render('DataBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('log' => $log));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The property name is actually:

```
private $stadiumID;
```

So you should do :

```
$repo->findOneBy(array('stadiumID' => $value));
```

so change this row:

```
$criteria = array("StadiumID" =>$stadium['StadiumID']);
```

to this:

```
$criteria = array("stadiumID" =>$stadium['StadiumID']);
```

Doctrine's main role is to connect your application layer(entites) to the database layer(tables). So doctrine tries to translate request comming from the application layer to the database. Even if you named your field in the database `"StadiumID"`or `"table_name_snake_case"`, when you call `findOneBy(array($property => $value))`, doctrine expects `$property` to refer to the property name, and it will translate this to SQL to something like `'SELECT FROM .... where StadiumID = :value'`

Comment: thanks for the great answer, are there any specific naming conventions that should be used for column names, is it a good idea to keep the column name the same as the property name in camelcase?

Comment: with great pleasure! If you do not mention the column name, doctrine will automatically transfor your property name (if in camelcase) to snake case. I find this to be very clear when using sql database, and somewhat of a best practice as it provides consistency. But it all depends on the business logic, and who will be handiling the database. Also some traits, such as Blameable name the columns in camel case (createdBy, updatedBy). You can also configure the naming strategy for doctrine, for your entities: https://coderwall.com/p/kj1reg/implementing-a-doctrine2-naming-strategy-in-symfony2

Answer (score 7):

For others who still have the problem, 
make sur that you have puted the sign '`=>`' instead of '`,`' when calling the function `findOneBy(...)` 
So instead of :

```
findOneBy(["code" , "Code-Example"]);
```

do that :

```
findOneBy(["code" => "Code-Example"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure the doctrine naming strategy is specified:

```yaml
doctrine:
    orm:
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
```

this is the doctrine's default naming strategy. This way doctrine knows how to map Entity property names to column names.
Note that, naming strategy configuration might be in different levels of doctrine configuration. For example, in another repo it is configured like this:

```yaml
doctrine:
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: shopping
        entity_managers:
            shopping:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
```